# Picasa shared albums to Google Photos

Tags: picasa, google-photos

Googles announces that Picasa will turn off early ( We’ll start rolling out these changes on May 1, 2016 )

But we have a lot of shared content on Picasa: https://picasaweb.google.com/amicscastellsf

Google Photos is able to share albums but not in this bulk way.

Is there a way to share all my albums though Google Photos like I'm doing now on Picasa?

Something like: https://photos.google.com/amicscastellsf <-- this link don't exists but will be wonderful to have it.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Are they not transferring the albums across to the new platform?

Comment: You can share albums using the web interface. Find all your shared albums [here](https://photos.google.com/shared).

Answer (score 0):

Now you can share your photos through google+.

You can find your albums here:

https://plus.google.com/115492017284938166486/photos?hl=es